# Online Access of Journals

Tags: journals, online-resource, online-learning

Recently I got myself enrolled in a PhD programme.

I want to know whether there is any website where one can get registered and get access to various different sites for journals like Jstor, Science Direct etc. I can’t access these sites outside of my university, although my college ID lets me access them from the campus. I am doing this course part-time, so I can’t always be inside the campus.

If I can get a common ID by paying some fee, I am ready for that. But that common login ID should work on different sites. Please let me know if there is any method.

Comment: Many uni libraries allow you to do it online. Have you checked?

Comment: Yes, I checked it but on the uni libraries all i get is the list of journals. On clicking it opens their website which requires login to access

Comment: If I understand you correctly that you want to access journals through your university, then you have to ask your university. Otherwise please [edit] your question to clarify.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft actually I asked my university but they said I can access journals using my college ID only from inside the campus and that too when I'm physically in the library or computer lab

Comment: Well, then [edit] your question to clarify what you want to ask instead.

Comment: I vote to close this question because the described problem is of infrastructural nature and does not belong on academia.SE

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know if it is the case at all universities, but at least at mine, journal access is tied to a specific IP range - as long as one connects to the internet within the campus, they can freely access the journals. However, the only way to gain access from elsewhere is through our university's VPN.

You should try asking at your university if they have something like that set up and available for students, but it's possible that they don't.

Comment: That's the right way. Greetings from a librarian.